# Missing return statement required return type: System.PageReference

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, salesforcedx

Trying to create a custom controller for a VF page following is the code for Apex class -

```
public class MyCustomVFPage_CTR {
    public String ObjectId {get;set;}
    public String ResponseCode {get;set;}
    public MyCustomVFPage_CTR () {
        ObjectId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ObjectId');
        ResponseCode = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ResponseCode');
    }
    public PageReference InitPage() {
        List<Customer_Issue__c> CustomerIssues = [SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Customer_Issue__c WHERE Id=:ObjectId LIMIT 1];
        if(!CustomerIssues.IsEmpty()){
            CustomerIssues[0].Status__c = ResponseCode;
            UPDATE CustomerIssues;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling this in a VF page -

```
<apex:page id="Page" showHeader="false" controller="MyCustomVFPage_CTR" action="{!InitPage}" cache="false">
    <apex:form>
        Thank you for your custom.
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Getting following error -

> Missing return statement required return type: System.PageReference

Tried to write a separate method but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

This method:

```
public PageReference InitPage() {
    List<Customer_Issue__c> CustomerIssues = [SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Customer_Issue__c WHERE Id=:ObjectId LIMIT 1];
    if(!CustomerIssues.IsEmpty()){
        CustomerIssues[0].Status__c = ResponseCode;
        UPDATE CustomerIssues;
    }
}
```

must return something (as it is not marked as returning `void` and so the compiler complains) and for the case where you don't want to move to a different page you return `null`:

```
public PageReference InitPage() {
    List<Customer_Issue__c> CustomerIssues = [SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Customer_Issue__c WHERE Id=:ObjectId LIMIT 1];
    if(!CustomerIssues.IsEmpty()){
        CustomerIssues[0].Status__c = ResponseCode;
        UPDATE CustomerIssues;
    }
    // Add the line below
    return null;
}
```